# is pg_multixact folder used for lock management

Tags: postgresql

Is pg_multixact folder used to manage a lock allocation table. If we consider a database which generates large number of transactions, are there a lot of writes in pg_multixact?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct connection between `pg_multixact` the number of database transaction. There is, however, a connection between row locks and multixacts:

`pg_multixact` is used to persist objects which, for lack of a better name, are called "multixacts". A multixact is an artifact that is necessary because of the way in which PostgreSQL implements row locks. In PostgreSQL, row locks are not kept in the shared memory locking table, but are stored on the `xmax` column of the table row itself. The value stored is the transaction number of the locking transaction. This presents a difficulty if several transactions (or subtransactions) lock the same table row. Since `xmax` can only contain a single transaction number, PostgreSQL creates a multixact that contains all locking (sub)transaction numbers and lock levels and stores the multixact ID in `xmax`.

Multixacts most frequently occur in connection with share locks on foreign key targets, but they can also happen if you use subtransactions (savepoints).

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive explanation, it helps me a lot to understand the internal mechanisms of Postgres. I have consulted your article regarding the xmax column to understand the difference between the case of the lock and the case of the deletion of a tuple https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/